# How to get pasta sauce out of your keyboard

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean a keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can laptop keyboard keys be removed and replaced?](https://superuser.com/questions/90549/how-can-laptop-keyboard-keys-be-removed-and-replaced)

I was eating lasagna and it spilled all over the keyboard. This was about 2 weeks ago. However, now whenever I type something my fingers are lightly stained red. I usually just lick it off, but the sauce is getting old.

Any ideas of how I can remove the sauce from underneath the keys?

Comment: "I usually just lick it off, but the sauce is getting old." What.

Comment: Have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/15609/can-i-put-keyboards-in-the-dishwasher

Comment: Apply pasta?...

Comment: This is the most disgusting thing I've ever read on SE.

Comment: Do you own a dog?

Comment: +1 for Kyle's pointer: the dishwasher always works for me.

Comment: @Rein Henrichs: Is that a challenge? ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner please no.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be best to just just get a new keyboard. They're pretty cheap.

I know you can remove the keys and clean underneath them, but I wouldn't recommend it. The one time I did that I removed about 3 keys and they all came falling off. I couldn't remember what keys went where and had a horrible time getting them back on. And even afterwards, they were always loose so I eventually got a new keyboard anyways. Perhaps it was the keyboard I had....

Answer (score 1):

Lol!! Well the keys can pop off, no matter if it is a desktop keyboard or laptop keyboard, so you can pop off the keys, clean them however you like, and clean underneath them with a damp cloth.

Comment: Bad advice for a laptop - not all those key mechanisms are designed to reattach easily!

Comment: @Shinrai, YES! All laptops have removeable keys, but most of them do not have re-attachable keys. :P

Comment: Interesting, good to know.  They seem like a challenge but I always thought you could get them back on.

Comment: I have an HP laptop that is missing some keys, they were not working anyways so I ripped them off, literally tearing the material. There was no other way of removing them, I tried. Well other than taking the keyboard out in once piece.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a regular keyboard / no or little "extra" circuitry (e.g. high end gaming ones)... I would recommend either:

1. Getting a new one
2. Unplugging, using a garden hose and try to wash it... possibly take off keys and wash separately, then re assemble... only reconnect when dry.